# How to plot shade red according to ratio variable using sgpanel plot

Tags: sas

I would like to plot dataset and obtain desired output with the right setup.

1. Plot the scatter such that the points are in shade red-color, from light red to dark red depending on the scale (ratio) of 0-1 (0=light red, 1=dark red).
2. Show the legend also showing the scale red color according to the ration 0-1 (point 1.)

**Data explanation:**

area - city (shortcut)
id - user id
var - variable
time - datetime
exit - consumer left
ratio - proportion (between 0-1)

Data sample and attempt plotting (obviously not correct):

```
data data;
input area $ id $ var $ time $ exit $ ratio $;
datalines;
A 1 1 1 0 0.18
A 1 1 2 0 0.11
A 2 1 1 1 0.14 
A 2 1 2 0 0.15 
A 2 1 3 0 0.14
A 3 1 1 0 0.17
A 3 1 2 0 0.19
A 3 1 3 1 0.21
A 3 1 4 0 0.14
B 4 2 1 0 0.14 
B 4 2 2 1 0.15
B 5 2 1 0 0.17
B 5 2 2 0 0.25
B 5 2 3 0 0.31
A 1 3 1 0 0.22
A 1 3 2 0 0.13
A 2 3 1 1 0.16 
A 2 3 2 0 0.11 
A 2 3 3 0 0.22
A 3 3 1 0 0.27
A 3 3 2 0 0.29
A 3 3 3 1 0.31
A 3 3 4 0 0.24
B 4 4 1 0 0.24 
B 4 4 2 1 0.35
B 5 4 1 0 0.47
B 5 4 2 0 0.15
B 5 4 3 0 0.21
;;
run;


data attrs;
input id $ risk $ fillcolor $;
datalines;
ratio 0.05 Verylightred
ratio 0.15 Lightred
ratio 0.20 Red
ratio 0.25 Darkred
ratio 0.30 Verydarkred
ratio 0.35 Verydarkstrongred
;           
run;



proc sgpanel data=data dattrmap=attrs;
    panelby area exit;
    scatter y=id x=var / markerattrs = (symbol = squarefilled) group=ratio attrid=ratio;
run;
```

Comment: Your attribute map needs to be a range map, then the mapping will work better. https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2022/03/30/missing-color-range-attribute-map.html If I have time later today I'll take a stab at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you closer.

- Ratio should be numeric to be graphed
- Ratio is continuous, how should it be used to group?
- For the colour on the data attribute map, the length of the colours is not long enough and risk should be numeric

I don't know exactly how to specify the ranges you'd like for the colours you'd like but this gets you closer using the automatic legend.

One way to get at this is to add the variable to the data set for each group and then you can control the colour of each group with the data attribute map. This would mean adding a column in the 'data' data set called ratio_group whcih maps to the values in the data attribute map table. Use that variable the group.

```
data data;
input area $ id $ var $ time $ exit $ ratio ;
datalines;
A 1 1 1 0 0.18
A 1 1 2 0 0.11
A 2 1 1 1 0.14 
A 2 1 2 0 0.15 
A 2 1 3 0 0.14
A 3 1 1 0 0.17
A 3 1 2 0 0.19
A 3 1 3 1 0.21
A 3 1 4 0 0.14
B 4 2 1 0 0.14 
B 4 2 2 1 0.15
B 5 2 1 0 0.17
B 5 2 2 0 0.25
B 5 2 3 0 0.31
A 1 3 1 0 0.22
A 1 3 2 0 0.13
A 2 3 1 1 0.16 
A 2 3 2 0 0.11 
A 2 3 3 0 0.22
A 3 3 1 0 0.27
A 3 3 2 0 0.29
A 3 3 3 1 0.31
A 3 3 4 0 0.24
B 4 4 1 0 0.24 
B 4 4 2 1 0.35
B 5 4 1 0 0.47
B 5 4 2 0 0.15
B 5 4 3 0 0.21
;;
run;


proc sgpanel data=data ;
    panelby area exit;
    scatter y=id x=var / markerattrs = (symbol = squarefilled size=10) 
                        colorresponse=ratio 
                        colormodel=(verylightred lightred red darkred verydarkred verydarkstrongred);
colaxis grid minorgrid;
rowaxis grid minorgrid;
run;
```

For marker size look at the SIZE option under the MARKERATTRS option.
For grids, look at the GRID/MINORGRID options under the COLAXIS and ROWAXIS statements.

[COLAXIS documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/grstatproc/p0vyc21mth0jrtn1c4jimudemip4.htm)

Comment: thanks, this should be enough, how can I control the size of the squarefilled? And how to add grid?

Comment: You can add the SIZE= option to control the symbol sizes. What type of grid are you referring to ?

Comment: background grid, separating eventually the squarefilled.

Comment: Modified answer.